# Swift protocol error

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I declared `protocol` in my Swift file:

```
protocol SocketManagerDelegate {
   func webSocketDidReceiveMessage(message:Message)
   func socketWasReconnected()
   func webSocketDidFailWithError(error:String)
}

import Foundation
import MDWamp
import SSKeychain

@objc(SocketManager)
class SocketManager: NSObject, MDWampClientDelegate{

   static let instance = SocketManager()

   var delegate:SocketManagerDelegate?
```

and I want to use the protocol in an ObjC file:

```
#import <Project-Swift.h>

@interface ChatManager () <SocketManagerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ChatManager.........
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Can't figure this out. Ideas?

In my `project-swift.h` file the variant `delegate` is not showing at all:

```
SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED("SocketManager")
@interface SocketManager : NSObject <MDWampClientDelegate>
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, strong) 
SocketManager * _Nonnull instance;)
+ (SocketManager * _Nonnull)instance SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MDWamp * _Null_unspecified wampConnection;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * _Nonnull socketUrlSecure;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * _Nonnull socketUrl;
```

Comment: Try @objc protocol SocketManagerDelegate:class { }

Comment: @MikeAlter your solution did the trick. Thanks. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Welcome ,Added  answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using swift protocol

```
protocol SocketManagerDelegate {
   func webSocketDidReceiveMessage(message:Message)
   func socketWasReconnected()
   func webSocketDidFailWithError(error:String)
}
```

that can't be used in obj-c without

`@Objc` statement

please replace your code with

```
@objc protocol SocketManagerDelegate:class {
   func webSocketDidReceiveMessage(message:Message)
   func socketWasReconnected()
   func webSocketDidFailWithError(error:String)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`project-swift.h` will not be generated/updated until your application has no error. If the application build fails `project-swift.h` will not be updated.

Its a kind of dead lock scenario.

**Solution :**

Step 1: Delete the confirmation of protocol in Objective - C file

```
#import <Project-Swift.h>

@interface ChatManager () /*<SocketManagerDelegate> delete this*/
@end
```

Step 2: Now clean and re-build project

Step 3: Now check Project-Swift.h that should now have your protocol declaration

Step 4: Now Confirm the protocol in your Objective -C file and build.

**EDIT:**

Swift constructs to appear in Project-Swift.h they should either be `NSObject` or `NSObjectProtocol`

Change your protocol def to

```
@objc protocol SocketManagerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
   func webSocketDidReceiveMessage(message:Message)
   func socketWasReconnected()
   func webSocketDidFailWithError(error:String)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your protocol doesn't confirm objC. Protocols in swift and in objC are different

add clas to your protocol:

```
@objc protocol SocketManagerDelegate: class {
   func webSocketDidReceiveMessage(message:Message)
   func socketWasReconnected()
   func webSocketDidFailWithError(error:String)
}
```

**UPDATE**

also add flag `@objc`

Comment: Adding `class` alone didn't solve the problem. Had to add `@objc` at the beginning.